How do we prevent a user from asking the same question on the staging ground twice?
The question: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79127914

This user asked a very very similar question before that was basically the same and just reworded to bypass the "needs major changes": https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79108983

What should be done in this situation?

As both questions are essentially “give me the code” questions both should fail to be promoted out of SG. Until they are not “give me the code” questions. Only one should be promoted one every becomes acceptable (doubtful). Both seem to be closed as caused by a typo
